# Install Unreal Engine 4.22.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: unreal-4, git, installer

I am trying to setup [NDDS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/Dataset_Synthesizer/blob/master/Documentation/NDDS.pdf) on Ubuntu 22.04 which requires Unreal Engine 4.22.2.

Looking at the oldest available versions of Unreal Engine for Linux, I don't find 4.22.2. What do you suggest to do?

[image]

The screenshot is from [this link](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/linux).

I did the following and didn't work. I am not sure how to install UE4.22 otherwise on Linux.

```
(base) mona@ada:/data2$ git clone https://monajalal:mytoken@github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git
Cloning into 'UnrealEngine'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5730157, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (469/469), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (296/296), done.
remote: Total 5730157 (delta 198), reused 429 (delta 169), pack-reused 5729688
Receiving objects: 100% (5730157/5730157), 25.44 GiB | 4.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3483034/3483034), done.
Updating files: 100% (161441/161441), done.
(base) mona@ada:/data2$ cd UnrealEngine/
(base) mona@ada:/data2/UnrealEngine$ git checkout 4.22
Updating files: 100% (231019/231019), done.
Branch '4.22' set up to track remote branch '4.22' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch '4.22'
(base) mona@ada:/data2/UnrealEngine$ ls
total 84K
drwxrwxr-x 11 mona mona 4.0K Nov 21 11:20 Engine
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  195 Nov 21 11:20 LICENSE.md
drwxr-xr-x  6 mona root 4.0K Nov 21 11:21 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  511 Nov 21 11:22 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  473 Nov 21 11:22 .editorconfig
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 5.7K Nov 21 11:22 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mona mona 1.7K Nov 21 11:22 Setup.sh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mona mona  208 Nov 21 11:22 Setup.command
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 1.3K Nov 21 11:22 Setup.bat
drwxrwxr-x  4 mona mona 4.0K Nov 21 11:22 Samples
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona 9.9K Nov 21 11:22 README.md
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mona mona  746 Nov 21 11:22 GenerateProjectFiles.sh
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mona mona  241 Nov 21 11:22 GenerateProjectFiles.command
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  418 Nov 21 11:22 GenerateProjectFiles.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 mona mona  269 Nov 21 11:22 UE4Games.uprojectdirs
drwxrwxr-x 30 mona mona 4.0K Nov 21 11:22 Templates
drwxrwxr-x  6 mona mona 4.0K Nov 21 11:22 .
drwxrwxr-x  8 mona mona 4.0K Nov 21 11:22 .git
(base) mona@ada:/data2/UnrealEngine$ git branch
* 4.22
  release
(base) mona@ada:/data2/UnrealEngine$ ./Setup.sh
Registering git hooks... (this will override existing ones!)
Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
Checking dependencies...
Updating dependencies:   0% (0/41030)...
Failed to download 'http://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies/UnrealEngine-4695293-7c9ba01492404dde9b3e7fbd27ede470/026c79c34842bdb82b8e333008adc73ca770d6db': The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. (WebException)
Result: 1
```

If I don't `git checkout 4.22` I have no problem with `Setup.sh`. But then, it installs the latest version of UE.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to download directly from unrealengine.com, but the [instructions linked from NDDS](https://web.archive.org/web/20180917034118/https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Building_On_Linux) say to get 4.22.2 via the [Unreal Engine private github repo](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/ue-on-github). Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah I am in the process of doing that. It's been very slow even though I have access to high-speed Ethernet. I'll report back on the process. Parts of instructions states it needs Ubuntu 16.04 (eol) so idk how that'll work out.

Comment: @Pikalek I used NDDS back in 2018 but a lot has changed in terms of requirements https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/pubs/2019-06_SIDOD%3A-A-Synthetic/SIDOD_tech_report.pdf

Comment: @Pikalek I updated the end of post with failed results of checking out 4.22 and trying Setup.sh, could you please have a look?